# How to get NaNs to work in rice compressed FITS files with astropy?

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I am having trouble with NaNs in astropy.fits.  When they are present anywhere in the file, we get white horizontal lines of NaNs across the entire image, but only if the HDU is compressed.  We realized that these lines are equal to the tile size.

We were hoping to use the zBLANK property to get these to go away, but it doesn't seem to work.  For example:

```
from astropy.io import fits as pyfits
import numpy as np

# Create date to be output as data_rd.  Then...
data_rd[np.where(np.isnan(data_rd)) = -2147483648

pri_hdu = pyfits.PrimaryHDU()
sec_hdu = pyfits.CompImageHDU(data=data_rd, tile_size=[10, 10], quantize_level=1000)
# Add other headers.  Then...
sec_hdu.header.append(("zBLANK", -2147483648, "The integer value to replace with NaNs"))

hdu = pyfits.HDUList([pri_hdu, sec_hdu])
hdu.writeto(product_filename, overwrite=True, checksum=True)
```

But when I view the data in the image, later, the data always looks like -2147483648, not NaN.

What am I doing wrong?  We can't get this to work with integer scaling, either.

Comment: Can't you do ``float("NaN")``?

Comment: @Score - 6 that has nothing to do with the question in this case.

Comment: how come it has nothing to do? @Iguananaut

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "these lines are equal to the tile size"?

Comment: In any case, there definitely seems to be some bugginess w.r.t. handling NaNs in compressed images.  In fact, I see now that if *any* tile contains NaNs then it is setting ZSCALE to NaN for that entire tile.  Furthermore it isn't handling ZBLANK well at all.  I think I will open a bug report about this; thanks for bringing it up.  I'm surprised it's never come up before.

Comment: I tried converting the numpy NaNs to regular python NaNs and it didn't seem to help.

@Iguananaut Thank you for your bug report!  I also find it hard to believe noone has seen this issue before.

Comment: No, it wouldn't help because the code simply is not handling NaNs correctly to begin with.

Comment: I forgot, here's the link to the issue: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/11212